# Remove array list using index value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there anyway to remove item from the list using index?.   I know this is common question but I didn't find yet the solution.  Thanks in advance!

```
let array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
remove_index = 2
```

output should = `one, two, four`

Comment: `array.splice(remove_index,1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use splice, syntax: `splice(start, deleteCount)`

```
let array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
array1.splice(2, 1);
```